# Windows Azure Runtime 2.7.0.0 cannot be found

Tags: c#, azure, service

I have a service which update data to CRM so maybe needed windows azure dll. recently i updated my NuGet packages for my project and now when i deploy my service, i get below error in Event Viewer:

> The description for Event ID 1015 from source Windows Azure Runtime
>   2.7.0.0 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is
>   corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local
>   computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> 13424
>   **ServiceName** Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024894
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

I have checked in my project that all the reference to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll` are pointing to 3.2.1 and Local Copy is set to True.

Can anyone gives me any pointer where i can start to look to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you are using Cloud Services given you talk about the runtime version, is that correct?

Comment: Not at all. All i am using is CRM SDK package to save data from my machine to CRM system. It worked but suddenly stopped and gives this error.

Comment: I also suddenly just started getting this error. Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: unbelievable that no one knows how to solve this.

Comment: I am also facing this issue from last one week

Comment: add nother to that - 2020 and still no idea why!

Comment: My problem was that I did not have the IIS management tooling installed: https://bytenota.com/how-to-solve-appcmd-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet/